# HTACCESS works wierd when removing last slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've opened a wildcard subdomain, which shows you the subfolder with the same name. For example, entering to `works.gincher.net/launch/index.php` will show you in `www.gincher.net/works/launch/index.php`. It works.

The problem starts when  the URL doesn't ends with file (whithout `index.php`) and when in the same time it doesn't end with slesh `/`. For example, if you'll enter to `works.gincher.net/launch`, it'll change the URL in the browser to `works.gincher.net/works/launch/`. I don't want the URL to change. I want it exactly as it was typed. So what's make the problem?

Here is my `.htaccess` file content:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php default.html Index.html Index.htm home.html 

ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
ErrorDocument 402 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gincher\.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.gincher\.net$
RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*?)::/\1/?
RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} !error.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to `mod_dir` adding a trailing slash and doing a redirect after `mod_rewrite` rules.

Try this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php default.html Index.html Index.htm home.html 
DirectorySlash off
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
ErrorDocument 402 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gincher\.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.gincher\.net$
RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*?)::/\1/?
RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} !error.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Now there is a problem with the inner files. For example, this code: `<img src="images/index/logo_white.png" alt="logo">`, if the URL doesn't ends with `/`, it tries to find the image in `http://works.gincher.net/images/index/logo_white.png`, while the image in `http://works.gincher.net/launch/images/index/logo_white.png` (and it returns 404 for some reason)...

Comment: Are you sure you have rules as shown? I only added `DirectorySlash off` and one rule that only affects directories due to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d`

Comment: it is still doesn't work. I think that you should make it to add the file name. For example, if you enter to `works.gincher.net/launch`, it will redirect you (with the URL in the browser) to `works.gincher.net/launch/index.php` (or `.html`, depends who exists)

Comment: ok try updated code, if that doesn't work try commenting `DirectorySlash off` line.

Comment: `# DirectorySlash off` bring back the first problem - `/works/` in the URL. Can you try adding automticly to the URL the index file? (`works.gincher.net/launch` -> `works.gincher.net/launch/index.php`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61515/discussion-between-gincher-and-anubhava).

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] ` this line right after `RewriteEngine On` fixed it. Thanks!